# XML Parser problem

Tags: objective-c, ios4

i have to parse data xml. 
any one suggest me a simple parser so i can get the data. please don't suggest of ASIHTTPrequest method..

In my xml file there are tad's in which data contain [CDATA] block. iseen this first time i get the null value for this tag

Comment: Posting your xml file would help others help you, a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) you will find a list of popular XML parser libraries for iOS and differences between them. I used TouchXML in my apps and it was really easy to use.

[ASIHTTPrequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) is not a parsing library, it's a wrapper for the CFNetwork API. It is used to perform basic HTTP requests and interacting with REST-based services (GET / POST / PUT / DELETE).